# Find the nearest point to (x,y) coordinates on mesh (MATLAB)

Tags: arrays, matlab

I create a mesh defined by the limits `xmin=-2`, `xmax=2`, `ymin=-2`, `ymax=2` and resolution `0.25`:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-2:.25:2, -2:.25:2);
```

I need find the nearest point to `x=0.9`, `y=1.1` with a function that serves to any coordinate.

Comment: I'd go with a quick-and-dirty `min(distance(x,y))` loop if it needed to be done in an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code computes all distances and finds the grid point that minimizes distance. It works even if the grid does not have a constant spacing.

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-2:.25:2, -2:.25:2); %// define grid (arbitrary)
x = 0.9; %// define point
y = 1.1;
d = (x-X).^2+(y-Y).^2; %// compute squared distances
[~, ind] = min(d(:)); %// minimize distance and obtain (linear) index of minimum
resultX = X(ind); %// use that index to obtain the result
resultY = Y(ind);
```

Comment: Can't you just use `distance` instead of handwriting the full equation?

Comment: @Adriaan Do you mean `pdist2`? Maybe you can use it, but not sure how in this case; and it would probably be slower

Comment: ah, yes, that's the one. Why is it slower than doing it by hand? Does `pdist2` also do all kinds of checks or so?

Comment: @Adriaan It would be `d = pdist2([x y], [X(:) Y(:)]);`. Yes, I mean slower because of checks, and because it internally uses loops

Comment: [pdist2](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) is also a part of the statistics toolbox which may not be available.

Comment: @bilbo17 Glad about that!

Answer (score 1):

For evenly-spaced grids, you can find this by direct calculation in `O(1)` rather than an `O(m*n)` search of the entire grid. I've separated `xres` and `yres` for flexibility, but you can of course combine them:

```
function [u, v] = getgrid(x, y, xmin, xmax, xres, ymin, ymax, yres)

   %// Find how many grid points we are from the center
   u=round(x/xres);     
   v=round(y/yres);

   %// Add the center point of grid to each offset
   u=u+(-xmin/xres)+mod(1+(xmax-xmin)/xres,2);
   v=v+(-ymin/yres)+mod(1+(ymax-ymin)/yres,2);

end
```

Here's a test script I wrote to drive the function:

```
xmin=-2; xmax=2; ymin=-2; ymax=2; res=0.25;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(xmin:xres:xmax, ymin:yres:ymax);

x=0.9
y=1.1
[u v]=getgrid(x, y, xmin, xmax, res, ymin, ymax, res)

[X(v,u), Y(v,u)]

x=-0.7
y=1.6
[u v]=getgrid(x, y, xmin, xmax, res, ymin, ymax, res)

[X(v,u), Y(v,u)]
```

And the output...

```
>> gogrid
x =  0.90000
y =  1.1000
u =  13
v =  13
ans =

   1   1

x = -0.70000
y =  1.6000
u =  6
v =  15
ans =

  -0.75000   1.50000
```

Answer (score 0):

If the size of your mesh is not too large, you can always calculate the distance to every point and find the minimum.

You define distance as d=(x-x0)^2+(y-y0)^2 and go through all the points in your mesh. 
Not super efficient, but does its work.

Comment: Please provide a working code. If you want to just throw a single-lined idea, use comments

Comment: I can't add comments :(

Comment: Then gain rep until you can. I'd not flag this as an outright not-an-answer, but it's close. We all went through that phase, just bear with it!